# Htaccess rewriting url with a $_GET empty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem, so my url will be like this :

> **www.site.fr/dashboard/posts/**

and for some widget on the posts page that will be like this

> **www.site.fr/dashboard/posts/add** or
>   **www.site.fr/dashboard/posts/remove/id(1,2...)**

But the real link will be

> **www.site.fr/dashboard/posts.php?action=add**
>   **www.site.fr/dashboard/posts.php?action=remove&id=(1,2...)**

For now i use that .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+) $1.php?action=$2 [NC,L]
```

But with this htaccess , that make just delete the ".php" and if the $_GET["action"] is empty, that doesn't work , that make an error.

If `$_GET["action"]` is **empty** , logically that say `action="index"` but I don't want to show in the url **/index/**.
And for the ID, if `$_GET["action"]` is equal to `"remove"` , I can get the `$_GET["id"]` else care of the `id`.

Thanks a lot, sorry for my bad english. I hope you'll understand what i means.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would do

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [L]
```